# Getting gskey: request denied

Tags: gyroscope-framework

Hey trying to insert and update a list items on one of my tabs but i'm getting the error msg "gskey: request denied error".

I don't understand what this error means. Can someone please clarify what would be the cause for this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to the checkgskey function on the server side gives the "gskey: request denied" error if the X-GSREQ-KEY in the POST request is missing.

X-GSREQ-KEY is automatically transmitted by a dedicated parameter in either ajxpgn or reload tab. The content of the gskey is output by the emitgskey function.

emitgskey('unique_phrase');
checkgskey('unique_phrase');

As long as the two unique phrases match, the request is not blocked. The unique phrase acts as a seed to compute a protective challenge that's unique to the user, session and location. In a way, the purpose of a GSKey is similar to a nounce.

[Additional documentation here](http://www.antradar.com/blog-prevent-xss-with-gskey).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the gskey wasn't being passed in with the call. You get that error when there's a key expected but not given.